# How display a image in react.js from a foreign key in node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a backend in node.js with a C.R.U.D to products. I used the multer library to upload the images. My database is postgreSQL, and the upload process is working.

I have 2 tables in the database: **products** and **files**. In the products table, I have a "thumb_id" column that is the foreign key linked to id of the files table.

When I send a request, I get the response with all correct informations, including the thumb_id. I can return the informations and fill the fields in the react app, but I can't display the image.

My question is: how I can display the image from a foreign key.

PS: In the files table, I have 3 columns: **id**, **name** and **path**. In the name, I have a original file name. In the path, I have a file name with crypto.

**Model: File**

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class File extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        //Fields registered by the files
        super.init({
            name: Sequelize.STRING,
            path: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        {
            sequelize,
        });
        return this;
    }
}

export default File;
```

**Controller: FileController**

```
import File from '../models/File';
import Product from '../models/Product';

class FileController {
    async store(req, res) {
        const { originalname: name, filename: path } = req.file;
        const file = await File.create({
            name,
            path
        });

        return res.json(file);
    }

async show(req, res) {
    try {
        //Comparing the params id with the database id
        const product = await Product.findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.params.productId
            },
            include: [File]
        });
        
        //If the id does not exist in the database...
        if(!product){
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Esse produto não existe.' });
        }

        return res.json(product);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Erro. ' });
    }
}
}

export default new FileController();
```

**Config: Multer**

```
import multer from 'multer';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { extname, resolve } from 'path';

export default {
    //Regarding file storage
    storage: multer.diskStorage({

        //Path that the file will be saved
        destination: resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'images'),

        //Regarding file name
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, res) => {
               if(err) return cb(err);

               //If there was no error, it will transform 16 bytes of random content into a hexadecimal string
               return cb(null, res.toString('hex') + extname(file.originalname))
            });
        }
    }),
}
```

**index of database file**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

import User from '../app/models/User';
import Product from '../app/models/Product';
import File from '../app/models/File';

import databaseConfig from '../config/database';

const models = [User, Product, File];

class Database {
    constructor(){
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        this.connection = new Sequelize(databaseConfig);

        models
            .map(model => model.init(this.connection))
            .map(model => model.associate && model.associate(this.connection.models));
    }
}

export default new Database();
```

**migration create-file**

```
//'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.createTable('files', {
          id: {
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
              allowNull: false,
              autoIncrement: true,
              primaryKey: true
          },
          name: {
              type: Sequelize.STRING,
              allowNull: false,
          },
          path: {
              type: Sequelize.STRING,
              allowNull: false,
              unique: true,
          },
          created_at: {
              type: Sequelize.DATE,
              allowNull: false,
          },
          updated_at: {
              type: Sequelize.DATE,
              allowNull: false,
          },
          deleted_at: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
          }
      });
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
      return queryInterface.dropTable('files');
  }
};
```

**migration add_thumb_to_product**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.addColumn(
            'products',
            'thumb_id',
            {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: { model: 'files', key: 'id' },
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                onDelete: 'SET NULL',
                allowNull: true
            }
        );
    },

    down: (queryInterface) => {
        return queryInterface.removeColumn('products', 'thumb_id');
    }
};
```

**------- Edit ----------**

**Model: Product**

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

class Product extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        //Fields registered by the product
        super.init({
            name: Sequelize.STRING,
            amount: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            price: Sequelize.FLOAT,
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            paranoid: true
        });

        return this;
    }

    //Relates the File table to the Product table. Save the file id inside the Product table.
    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.File, { foreignKey: 'thumb_id' });
    }
}

export default Product;
```

Result of request.

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Samsung Galaxy M10",
  "amount": 10,
  "price": 950.99,
  "createdAt": "2020-07-19T15:07:07.177Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-07-20T16:19:42.938Z",
  "deletedAt": null,
  "thumb_id": 1,
  "File": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "profile.jpg",
    "path": "7910cddcf0830edae3a0508f863893e4.jpg",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-19T21:52:34.887Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-19T21:52:34.887Z"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import routes from './routes';
import cors from 'cors';

import './database';

class App {
    constructor() {
        this.server = express();
        this.middlewares();
        this.routes();
    }

    middlewares() {
        this.server.use(cors());
        this.server.use('/images', express.static('../images'));
        this.server.use(express.json());
    }

    routes() {
        this.server.use(routes);
    }
}

export default new App().server;
```

Comment: So all you essentialy need is to join files table to products table on thumb_id. So the only relevant code would be where you query the products table, which you didn't post. Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: ready, I had forgotten

Comment: I still don't see Products.find. Anyway you need to tell sequlize to include the file by using `Products.find({ where: { ...}, include: [models.file]})`

Comment: Oops, thanks. Now I got some more information besides "thumb_id", like "name" and "path". But how can I show this in react.js? Sorry for so much question, I'm kind of new.

I already changed the code: "show" method in the ProductController

Comment: Use something like this `<img src={path}>`

Comment: the result of the path is ""path": "7910cddcf0830edae3a0508f863893e4.jpg",". 

would the way you're talking work?

Comment: Is the image accessible at example.com/7910cddcf0830edae3a0508f863893e4.jpg ? If so then it shoud work.

Comment: Unfortunately not. That is the problem, I am unable to access it. The images are inside an "images" folder outside src

Comment: So simply prepend the path with images like so `<img src={'/images/' + path}>`

Comment: It still didn't work. The "images" folder is inside the node.js server, so maybe I am not able to access it

Comment: Use express static to serve files https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html if you are using express though

Comment: Even doing this method that you went through didn't work. I added the app.js file to the post

Comment: Have you tried `express.static('images')` where's the images folder relative to your app.js?